# adding multiple layouts to horizontal swipe view

Tags: android, android-fragments, horizontalscrollview

I have added a horizontal scroll view and in the layout I have added reference to two fragments such that both  the fragments are visible in the scroll.

the problem is when I enter values in the left layout I want the value to be displayed in the right layout.

I am using an interface for the same, but its not working. as in I keep getting null pointer exception for the same.. How to get around this??

this is the main class fragment

```
 public static SliderRightAdapter sliderRightAdapterFragment; <-- this calls the second layout


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.f_pp, container, false);

    sliderRightAdapterFragment = (SliderRightAdapter) getActivity()
            .getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.secondary_sliderProduct_description);

    return view;

}
```

.
.
.
.
this is where i am getting null pointer exception on sliderRightAdapterfragment

```
    interfaceObject.onButtonClick(CGS, sliderRightAdapterFragment);
```

and this is where it is initialized...

```
    sliderRightAdapterFragment = PDFinterface.sliderRightAdapterFragment;
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm seeing, you're letting the fragments communicate directly with each other. 
I'd recommend against it, since this can quickly lead to maintaining unused references, as fragments can have quite diverse lifecycles. The idea behind fragments is to have small segments of functionality which can communicate with their parent some information.

I think a better way to approach would be to use the parent activity as a form of 'manager' between these two fragments.

Instead of maintaining a static reference to the other fragment, store a normal reference to the activity, preferably in the form of a listener interface the activity implements. Then you'd use the findFragmentById/Tag to notify the other fragment of the change. All in all, this would look something like this:

Fragment:

```
public interface ActivityListener {
    void onText(String text);
}

private ActivityListener listener;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    if(activity instanceof ActivityListener) {
        listener = (ActivityListener) activity;
    }
    // else some error
}

@Override
public void onDetach(Activity activity) {
    // to make absolutely sure you don't maintain a reference to a killed activity
    listener = null;
}
```

Activity:

```
@Override
public void onText(String text) {
    Fragment frag = getSupportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(<someId>);
    // notify with text information
}
```

Something like this should work fine.